# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:argumentArray: Only Evaluating First Argument

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm having some trouble using `NSPredicate` `predicateWithFormat:argumentArray`:.  In this example, `serverIDList` is array of strings.  Results is an array of `NSManagedObjects` with an attribute named "flid" which is a string.

```
NSMutableString *predicateString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[predicateString appendString:@"(flid IN %@)"];

[results filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString argumentArray:serverIDList]];
```

The problem is that `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString argumentArray:serverIDList]` evaluates to "flid IN '2155'", which is only the first value of the array `serverIDList`.    I can't seem to get the predicate to evaluate the entire array.  Is there something missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(flid IN %@)" argumentArray:serverIDList]
```

is equivalent to

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(flid IN %@)", id1, id2, ..., idN]
```

where `id1`, ..., `idN` are the elements of the array `serverIDList`.
That should explain why only the first element is evaluated.

What you probably want is

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(flid IN %@)", serverIDList]
```

*Remark:* I would recomment *not* to create predicates as strings first. The chances for
quoting or escaping errors are quite high. Use only `predicateWithFormat` with a 
constant format string. If you have to combine predicates dynamically at runtime,
use `NSCompoundPredicate`.