# Using NSPredicate with array for cloudKit search

Tags: ios, nspredicate

When using a `NSPredicate`, I'm trying to search all objects (strings) contained within an array. The code sample below works but the predicate only collects the object in the first index only??  The `NSPredicate` is used for a `CKQueryOperation`.
Each `Record` has a value for a key named `Category`.

```
    let array: [String] = ["Education", "Sport", "TV and Film"]

    // select all records
    //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Category = %@", category )



    let predicate = NSPredicate (format: "Category == %@", argumentArray: array)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "quizRecord", predicate: predicate)

    // get just one value only
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

  //code works but only queries Records with the Category for "Education"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059170/nspredicate-predicatewithformatargumentarray-only-evaluating-first-argument ?

Comment: @Larme that question / answer was in objectiveC - I have tried lots of variations but I can translate it to Swift.

Comment: how do you get more than one value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
"Category == %@"
```

With:

```
"Category IN %@"
```

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error with your answer: 'CKException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: Category IN "Education" (Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=12 "Invalid operator in <Category IN "Education">: Unsupported operator: IN" UserInfo={ck_isComparisonError=true,

Comment: I know what's going on here. Change your predicate line from:
    `let predicate = NSPredicate (format: "Category == %@", argumentArray: array)` to `let predicate = NSPredicate (format: "Category == %@", argumentArray: [array])`. notice the array should be put inside an argumentArray parameter array. This should be done in conjunction with the `IN` change inside the predicate described above.

Comment: Yep thats done it ! Brilliant job. Thanks Danny I really appreciate your help

Comment: I am a having the same issue with only the first element of the search array being matched. I tried Danny's solution, but get back an error: "Filter EQUALS cannot be applied with filter value type STRING_LIST". Using Xcode 8.3.2 & Swift 3. What does one do now?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as Peter Wiley. The solution I found was a mash up of Danny Bravo's solution and comment on that solution.

```
let arrayPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Name IN %@", argumentArray: [names])
```

To get multiple results I needed to use both the keyword "IN" in the format and wrap my argumentArray with [].